# Behavior of parameter expansion

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I always thought that with a parameter expansion such as `$foo`, the shell replaces `$foo` with the contents of the parameter before executing the command. 
If, for example, I set

```
foo='`'
```

Why then, does

```
ls $foo
```

have different behavior than

```
ls `
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` has several distinct phases in the processing of a command line. Relevant here are the parsing phase and the expansion phase. The phases
occur in order, and one phase does not begin until the previous phase completes.

In the first example, the *parser* never sees the backquote; that is supplied by the expansion of `$foo` which occurs after parsing is complete. As a result, a literal backquote is passed to `ls` as an argument.

In the second example, the parser sees an unquoted backquote, which indicates the beginning of a command substitution.

Comment: Important addition: while the content of variables isn't fully parsed, it does undergo [word splitting and wildcard expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108963/expansion-of-a-shell-variable-and-effect-of-glob-and-split-on-it#109074), which you usually don't want. So it's almost always a good idea to put double-quotes around variable references (e.g. `ls "$foo"`) to prevent this additional processing.

Comment: I think the lack of quotes in the original question was intentional, or at least relevant, in that the comparison was of `$foo` to an unquoted backquote, not `"$foo"` to ``"`"``. But in practice, yes, quote the expansion.